# syntax to replace regex at json data where value appear multiple times

Tags: regex

i have json data as below

```
Facility/Hospital A/Test Machine One for Bag/Test Bag 1
Facility/Hospital A/Test Machine One for Bag
Facility/Test Bag Master
```

my application allowed user to do regex and replace via API POST

i have tried below, but the outcome isn't meet my expectation.

```html
{
  "msg": [
    {
      "type": "RENAME",
      "regexMatch" : "Bag(.*)",
      "regexReplace" : "Tote$1"
    }
  ]
}
```

outcome

```
Facility/Hospital A/Test Machine One for Tote/Test Bag 1
Facility/Hospital A/Test Machine One for Tote
Facility/Test Tote Master
```

expected outcome

```
Facility/Hospital A/Test Machine One for Tote/Test Tote 1
Facility/Hospital A/Test Machine One for Tote
Facility/Test Tote Master
```

is the "regexMatch" : "Bag(.*)", being used incorrectly?

please advise what should be the regex to replace all Bag to Tote when the data looks like "Facility/Hospital A/Test Machine One for Bag/Test Bag 1"

Comment: If you want to replace bag to tote, then why use .* in the regex?

Comment: @RajeshG i might have data which looks like Bag1, BagA, Bag 123

Comment: k then Bag1, BagA, Bag 123 should change to Tote1, ToteA, Tote 123 or all the pattern should simply replaced as Tote?

Comment: Use `"regexMatch" : "Bag([^,/]*)",`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works. many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a negated character class `[^,/]` to match any char but a comma and forward slash:

```
{
  "msg": [
    {
      "type": "RENAME",
      "regexMatch" : "Bag([^,/]*)",
      "regexReplace" : "Tote$1"
    }
  ]
}
```